# Reflection - from Type to Class (not instance of class)

Tags: c#, reflection, json-deserialization

How do I write something like this?

```
string json = null;
Type[] types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
var carTypes = (from type in types
                 where type.IsClass && type == typeof(Car)
                 select type);
foreach(var carType in carTypes )
{
    string typeName = carType .Name;
    string jsonFile = typeName + ".json";
    json = File.ReadAllText(jsonFile);

    // How can I not hardcode "Porche" here and instead use "carType"?
    IList<Porche> cars = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Porche>>(json);
}
```

Here, **Porche** is a sub class of **Car** - Both "**Porche**" and "**Car**" are **Class**. In additional to Porche, we have Toyata, BMW, Tesla... I want to dynamically retrieve them via Reflection (avoid hardcoding)
**"cars"** is a list of **instances** of cars.

"**carType**" is **Type**.
How can I use "carType" in JsonConvert.DerserializeObject which take List as argument?

```
IList<someReflectionAPI(carType)> cars = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<someReflectionAPI(carType)>>(json);
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share some sample JSON with the expected output?

Comment: you cant do what you want, generic parameters must be known at compile time. the compiler  just wont give you this degree of freedom. however this all seems a little suspicious

Comment: Can this sort of thing be done with Python?

Comment: Sample json? [
  {
    "Manufacturer": "Tesla",
    "Model": "model 3",
    "numSeats": "4",
 "Size" : "mid"
  },
  {
    "Manufacturer": "Tesla",
    "Model": "model S",
    "numSeats": "4",
 "Size" : "mid"
  },
  {
    "Manufacturer": "BMW",
    "Model": "M3",
    "numSeats": "4",
 "Size" : "mid"
  },
  {
    "Manufacturer": "BMW",
    "Model": "X3",
    "numSeats": "4",
 "Size" : "compact"
  }
]

Comment: since Porche is a subclass of Car, your where clause in linq should be where type.IsClass && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Car)) . This and the ans by thepirat000 below should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the generic type at runtime with [MakeGenericType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype?view=netframework-4.7.2) and use the non-generic overload of `DeserializeObject`:

```
var listOfType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(carType);
var cars = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, listOfType);
```